# Finding equal intervals for two divided ranges

Tags: python, numpy

I have been scratching my head trying several approaches without success.
I have four values `min1,max1,min2,max2` and the condition is that `min2>max1`

This values can be negatives, can be floats.

I want to subdivide these into subintervals with the conditions:

1. the subintervals have to be of the same length
2. They should be contained in the original intervals

I tried

```
import numpy as np

# Define the intervals
min1, max1 = 0, 6
min2, max2 = 8, 17

# Check if min2 is greater than max1
if min2 <= max1:
    raise ValueError("Invalid intervals: min2 must be greater than max1.")

# Specify the number of intervals
num_intervals = 5  # Adjust as needed

# Calculate the length of each interval
total_length = max2 - min1
interval_length = total_length / num_intervals

# Generate array with intervals
intervals = np.linspace(min1, max2, num=num_intervals + 1)

print("Original intervals:")
print(f"Interval 1: [{min1}, {max1}]")
print(f"Interval 2: [{min2}, {max2}]")

print("\nDivided intervals:")
for i in range(num_intervals):
    start_point = intervals[i]
    end_point = start_point + interval_length
    print(f"Interval {i + 1}: [{start_point}, {end_point}]")
```

but this is obviously incorrect since the results

```
Original intervals:
Interval 1: [0, 6]
Interval 2: [8, 17]

Divided intervals:
Interval 1: [0.0, 3.4]
Interval 2: [3.4, 6.8]
Interval 3: [6.8, 10.2]
Interval 4: [10.2, 13.6]
Interval 5: [13.6, 17.0]
```

we see that interval 2 max is greater than max1 and also interval 3 min is less than min2

in reality this should have been for example

```
Interval 1: [0.0, 3.0]
Interval 2: [3.0, 6.0]
Interval 3: [8.0, 11.0]
Interval 4: [11.0, 14.0]
Interval 5: [14.0, 17.0]
```

(take into account that this is not the only solution. it could also have been

```
Interval 1: [0.0, 1.5]
Interval 2: [1.5, 3.0]
Interval 3: [3.0, 4.5]
Interval 4: [4.5, 6.0]
Interval 5: [8.0, 9.5]
Interval 6: [9.5, 11.0]
Interval 7: [11.0, 12.5]
Interval 8: [12.5, 14.0]
Interval 9: [14.0, 15.5]
Interval 10: [15.5, 17.0]
```

It seems simple but I am stuck.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: several intervals that are contained within min1 max1 and then more intervals contained between min2 max2

Comment: Please share what is your expected output in numbers

Comment: I wrote a simple example

Comment: `Interval 4: [4.5, 6.0]`
`Interval 5: [8.0, 9.5]` why did you miss 6.01 - 7.99 ?

Comment: @User12345 Rule #2. The result intervals have to be contained in the original intervals. 6.01 -7.99 are outside the original intervals